# Why does ArcGIS 10 Convert Time Field geoprocessing tool return <null> when using custom format?

Tags: arcgis-10.0, arcgis-desktop, convert, time

I have dates in my attribute table that are stored as strings - they look like 02/22/2012 (mm/dd/yyyy) - and I would like to convert them to Date type. When I try to input a custom date format in the Convert Time Field geoprocessing tool it returns  in all the records and I am not sure what I am doing wrong. I've tried MM/dd/yyyy and MMddyyyy - is there something I'm missing about setting up a custom date format? Or, is there another way I can do this?

Answer (score 3):

I created a shapefile with a string field with dates in the 02/22/2012 format and was able to convert it using the "Convert Time Field" tool after a couple tries.
On my successful attempt I created a new field of type date and then ran the date conversion tool.
For the custom format I used "MM/dd/yyyy". I also specified the newly created date field as the output time field.
I checked the method with errors in the strings and even a string like "2/5/12" was converted to 2/5/2012. 
(My initial failures came because I assumed the tool would create a new date field for me, that didn't happen during my test.)

I hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you AtlasSteve - I tried this first (creating a new empty field with date type) and it appears to have worked!

Answer (score 2):

I just tested this and MM/dd/yyyy worked okay for me.  Is it possible that there is a value in your string field that is not in this format?  Maybe there are one or two records hiding in your string field with something like '2/22/2012' instead of '02/22/2012'.

Comment: MM/dd/yyyy worked for me too - Cyrus' suggestion of checking your string field for rows that don't match the expected format seems sensible - could be worth testing on a table with just one or two rows if you have not already done so - and maybe "breaking" the format of a row to see what that does to the expected output

Answer (score 1):

I have been able to do this using ArcGIS 10.2.

When I run the Convert Time Field tool on a GDB table of 20000 rows, it says it has completed successfully but no values are updated in the target field (nulls).

However, if I run it after first **selecting all the records** in the table (obviously you need to be in ArcMap to do this), then it updates the values as expected!